# What is the  structure of "Long time passing"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-patterns

> **WHERE HAVE ALL THE FLOWERS GONE**
>   words and music by Pete Seeger
>
> Where have all the flowers gone?
>   *Long time passing*
>   Where have all the flowers gone?
>   Long time ago
>   Where have all the flowers gone?
>   Girls have picked them every one
>   When will they ever learn?
>   When will they ever learn?
>   .....

What is the exact meaning of "Long time passing"? What kind of construct is it?

NB: Of course I can infer an approximate meaning, but I can't recognize the structure
**[adj] [noun] [present participle]** as a stand alone one.

Comment: I think your title could be improved if you mention that you're looking for the construct more than the meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"long" is an adjective. "time" is a noun, as well as the subject, while "passing" is a present participle, the verb.

"Long time passing" refers to a great amount of time that **has passed** by since the flowers were gone. This can be seen by the fact that the fourth line "Long time ago" indicates something that has happened in the past.

Most songs don't have a correct grammatical structure, and this one doesn't really have one either. I think the correct form would have been:

> Long time passed.

But because a song needs a rhythmn, an additional syllable had to be added, hence the "passing".
Of course, he could have done:

> Long time has passed.

Comment: So the structure is ... wrong :)

Comment: It's... informal.

Comment: @belisarius - If you worry a lot about sentence structure being "right" in folk songs, I highly suggest you stay away from Bob Dylan.